# Kohana 3.2 routing issue

Tags: url-routing, kohana, kohana-3.2

I have set up my routes so that most classes are called in the standard `controller/action` style. However for my front end I don't want users to see the action being called, so all front end pages have their own controller and use the index action. These are my routers in bootstrap:

```
Route::set('normal', '<controller>(/<action>(/<arguments>))', 
    array(
        'arguments'     => '.*'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'    => 'admin',
        'action'        => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<arguments>))', 
    array(
        'arguments'     => '.*',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'    => 'home',
        'action'        => 'index',
    ));
```

I currently have three front end pages, home, about_us and services. They all work great if I don't pass any arguments in through the URL, but the problem occurs if I try to pass an argument in through the URL into arguments. In services there is only `action_index()` to display the page and it checks for any arguments, and displays results based on the argument. However if I try to browse to `/services/1` to pass in 1 as an argument I get this 404 error:

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL services/1 was not found on this server.
```

It just uses the first route, normal. Once it can't find the action it doesn't even try to use the second route, which would work. If I swap the order of the routes then it works, but all my other classes that use the first controller stop working as all my actions get passed to `action_index()` as arguments.

How can I get this working? Why when the first route doesn't work does Kohana not go on to the second route?

Comment: Try this syntanx:`Route::set('normal', '(/<controller>(/<action>(/<arguments>)))',` and  `Route::set('default', '(/<controller>(/<arguments>))', `

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to create controller per route. You can create custom routes (route names) and specify controller and action name. Read the documentation for further explanation. [Routing](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing)

For arguments try this:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<arguments>))', 
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'    => 'home',
        'action'        => 'index',
    ));
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as what I already have, except for the rule for arguments?